# how to find address of string in binary in gdb?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, disassembly

So here is the source code of the binary:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return 0;
}
```

and below is the compilation of this source code:

> @CTOS:/tmp/mytemp$ gcc helloWorld.c -o helloWorld

Now when I disassemble my binary in gdb as below:

```
Reading symbols from helloWorld...
(No debugging symbols found in helloWorld)
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000001149 <+0>:     endbr64 
   0x000000000000114d <+4>:     push   %rbp
   0x000000000000114e <+5>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000001151 <+8>:     lea    0xeac(%rip),%rax     
   0x0000000000001158 <+15>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x000000000000115b <+18>:    call   0x1050 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000001160 <+23>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000001165 <+28>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000001166 <+29>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.

(gdb) p (char*)0xeac
$1 = 0xeac <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xeac>
```

Now I want to know the address of the "Hello World" string which is passed inside puts function call, I want to display the address in gdb by gdb command. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step (s) into the print yield this output:

```
__GI__IO_puts (str=0x555555556004 "Hello World") at ioputs.c:35
```

Another option is to look search for string in text segment of the process.  You do that first by looking at process mappings then use `find` for the string.

```
(gdb) info proc mappings
process 212970
Mapped address spaces:

          Start Addr           End Addr       Size     Offset objfile
      0x555555554000     0x555555555000     0x1000        0x0 /home/allan/a.out
      0x555555555000     0x555555556000     0x1000     0x1000 /home/allan/a.out
      0x555555556000     0x555555557000     0x1000     0x2000 /home/allan/a.out
      0x555555557000     0x555555558000     0x1000     0x2000 /home/allan/a.out
      0x555555558000     0x555555559000     0x1000     0x3000 /home/allan/a.out
      0x7ffff7dd7000     0x7ffff7df9000    0x22000        0x0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
      0x7ffff7df9000     0x7ffff7f53000   0x15a000    0x22000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
      0x7ffff7f53000     0x7ffff7fa2000    0x4f000   0x17c000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
      0x7ffff7fa2000     0x7ffff7fa6000     0x4000   0x1ca000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
      0x7ffff7fa6000     0x7ffff7fa8000     0x2000   0x1ce000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
      0x7ffff7fa8000     0x7ffff7fae000     0x6000        0x0 
      0x7ffff7fca000     0x7ffff7fcc000     0x2000        0x0 
      0x7ffff7fcc000     0x7ffff7fd0000     0x4000        0x0 [vvar]
      0x7ffff7fd0000     0x7ffff7fd2000     0x2000        0x0 [vdso]
      0x7ffff7fd2000     0x7ffff7fd3000     0x1000        0x0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
      0x7ffff7fd3000     0x7ffff7ff3000    0x20000     0x1000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
      0x7ffff7ff3000     0x7ffff7ffb000     0x8000    0x21000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
      0x7ffff7ffc000     0x7ffff7ffd000     0x1000    0x29000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
      0x7ffff7ffd000     0x7ffff7ffe000     0x1000    0x2a000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
      0x7ffff7ffe000     0x7ffff7fff000     0x1000        0x0 
      0x7ffffffde000     0x7ffffffff000    0x21000        0x0 [stack]

(gdb) find 0x555555554000, 0x555555559000, "Hello World"
0x555555556004
```